# Removing a parent element on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic

I am having trouble creating a dynamic form where a user can add and remove a text field. The functionality to add an extra field works fine, but removing the field just cannot seem to work.

My html is:

```
<div class="formItem" id="members">
  <label for="workgroup">Add Members:</label>
  <br />
  <a href="#" id="addMember">Add another member</a>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="members[]" placeholder="Enter email" autocomplete="off" />
  </p>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$('#addMember').on('click', function() {
  $('<p><input type="text" name="members[]" placeholder="Enter email" autocomplete="off" /><a href="#" id="removeMember">Remove</a></p>').appendTo('#members');
  return false;
});

$('#removeMember').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the click listener before actually creating the element, use:

```
$('#members').on('click', '#removeMember', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

see these examples http://api.jquery.com/on/#entry-examples

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
$(document).on('click','#removeMember', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```